# Where is the error that is resulting in this Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./users/UserSection.jsx" message?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the browser's cosole I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./users/UserSection.jsx"
```

Yet I have looked over my UserSection file and directory for any syntax or typo errors and I cannot identify why it cannot find the module.

Here is the UserSection.jsx component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import UserForm from './UserForm.jsx';
import UserList from './UserList.jsx';

class UserSection extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div className='support panel panel-primary'>
                <div className='panel-heading'>
                    <strong>Users</strong>
                </div>
                <div className='panel-body users'>
                    <UserList {...this.props.} />
                    <UserForm {...this.props} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

UserSection.PropTypes = {
    users: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    setUserName: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default UserSection
```

And here is the App.jsx file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ChannelSection from './channels/ChannelSection.jsx';
import UserSection from './users/UserSection.jsx';
import MessageSection from './messages/MessageSection.jsx';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            channels: [],
            users: [],
            messages: [],
            activeChannel: {}
        };
    }
    // componentDidMount(){
    //  let ws = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');
    // }
    addChannel(name){
        let {channels} = this.state;
        channels.push({id: channels.length, name});
        this.setState({channels});
        // TODO: Send to Server
    }
    setChannel(activeChannel){
        this.setState({activeChannel});
        // TODO: Get Channel Messages
    }
    setUserName(name){
        let {users} = this.state;
        users.push({id: users.length, name});
    }
    addMessage(body){
        let {messages, users} = this.state;
        let createdAt = new Date;
        let author = users.length > 0 ? users[0].name : 'anonymous';
        messages.push({id: messages.length, body, createdAt, author});
        this.setState({messages});
        // TODO: Send to Server
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className='app'>
                <div className='nav'>
                    <ChannelSection  
                      {...this.state} 
                      addChannel={this.addChannel.bind(this)}
                      setChannel={this.setChannel.bind(this)} />
                    <UserSection
                      {...this.state}
                      setUserName={this.setUserName.bind(this)} />
                </div>
                    <MessageSection
                      {...this.state}
                      addMessage={this.addMessage.bind(this)} />
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default App
```

Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Okay guys, here is the project strucuture:

```
├── app.css
├── bundle.js
├── components
│   ├── App.jsx
│   ├── channels
│   │   ├── Channel.jsx
│   │   ├── ChannelForm.jsx
│   │   ├── ChannelList.jsx
│   │   └── ChannelSection.jsx
│   ├── messages
│   │   ├── Message.jsx
│   │   ├── MessageForm.jsx
│   │   ├── MessageList.jsx
│   │   └── MessageSection.jsx
│   └── users
│       ├── User.jsx
│       ├── UserForm.jsx
│       ├── UserList.jsx
│       └── UserSection.jsx
├── index.html
├── index.js
```

by the way I have been troubleshooting it as well and the original error is gone, now I am getting these errors:

```
React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `App`            

Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `App`
```

Comment: Can you post your folder structure?

Comment: Are you using webpack? can you confirm you have a `.jsx` loader?

Comment: @BradBumbalough, I posted my webpack.config.js file. Also my App.jsx is inside my Components folder. Channels, Users and Messages folders is also inside my Components folder.

Comment: could you please show us a project strucuture... use tree command to help

Comment: We really need to see the file structure, with the directories and their contents. If the file within channels is being loaded, and the users folder is in the same level as channels, there's an error in what you typed: './users/UserSection.jsx'

Comment: okay guys I have provided the project structure.

Comment: by the way I have been troubleshooting it as well and the original error is gone, now I am getting these errors: bundle.js:1285 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `App`Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `App`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the error saying that `React.createClass` is null and you are certain it's an actual component, there are two common issues that could be causing this.

#### 1. You forgot to export the custom component

It's easy to forget when you whip up a new component, but you need to ensure your calling `module.exports = MyCustomComponent` or if you're using ES6, `export default MyCustomComponent`.

#### 2. You're using an `index.js` file in your folder to export all child components

When I'm using folders to organize components, I often use an `index.js` file to manually export all the nested components, so I can easily call `import {Component1, Component2} from './components'`. When I get this error it's because I forgot to add my new component to the `index.js` file. I don't think this applies to your scenario, but am including it for others who may have a similar issue.

Comment: thank you for this answer. I will be bookmarking this page under my Reactjs folder for future reference.

Comment: Glad to hear! for the benefit of others you might think of editing the title to be more in line which the error message so they can easily find it too.